# JDBC programms running long time performance issue

Tags: linux, performance, oracle, jdbc, java

My program has an issue with Oracle query performance, I believe the SQL have good performance, because it returns quickly in SQLPlus.

But when my program has been running for a long time, like 1 week, the SQL query (using JDBC) becomes slower (In my logs, the query time is much longer than when I originally  started the program). When I restart my program, the query performance comes back to normal.

I think it is could be something wrong with the way I use the preparedStatement, because the SQL I'm using does not use placeholders "?" at all. Just a complex select query.

The query process is done by a util class. Here is the pertinent code building the query:

```
public List<String[]> query(String sql, String[] args) {
    Connection conn = null;
    conn = openConnection();
    conn.setAutocommit(true);
    ....
    PreparedStatement preStatm = null;
    ResultSet rs = null;
    ....//set preparedstatment arg code 
    rs = preStatm.executeQuery();
      ....
    finally{
           //close rs
           //close prestatm
           //close connection
     }
 }
```

In my case, the args is always null, so it just passes a query sql to this query method. Is that possible this way could slow down the DB query after program long time running? Or I should use statement instead, or just pass args with "?" in the SQL? How can I find out the root cause for my issue? Thanks.

Comment: Degradation in performance is probably related to your code not releasing resources (example: closing connections).

Comment: @Alfabravo, thanks your comment. But I already close the connection resource one by one in the finally block, is that you mean, there is still some other place may not close the connection or unrelease the resource?

Comment: Yup. The other option is the way your query is built. Could you show it to us?

Comment: Have you monitored Oracle's sessions? Are connections always get closed? Do a select on `v$session` when the system is getting slow, and see how many active sessions are there.

Comment: @Alfabravo, sorry the SQL included too much business info, I cannot just post here, but we turnning for the query plan. It should be fine, I found once the database is idle (weekend, no body use the system), it would be running very fast. Not sure if this means something.

Comment: @AmirPashazadeh, I closed the connection in the final block, it is something like if (conn!=null) conn.close(), so I believe the un-released DB resources is not the root cause. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe problem in jdbc cache... [oracle spec](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/java.111/b31224/concache.htm)
Try to turn it off.
or try to reinit the driver some times (one time per day)

Comment: thanks your answer, how to trun it off with pure jdbc? We are using a simple JDBC standalong application, no web container to mantain a datasource. And what is your mean of re-init the driver? How to do that? Do you mean re-load the Oracle driver class?

Comment: I had the same problem. After one and a half week of searching I found out that Oracle jdbc datasource had turned on cache. After disabling it, this delay(I am running one select query million times and delay appears after one hundred thousands) disappears and query runs in constant time.

Answer (score 0):

You first need to look into data that will help you see where you are spending most your time, guessing is not an option when performance tunning.

So I would recommend get solid data that pin points the layer presenting the issue (JAVA or DB).

For this I would suggest to look at AWR and ASH reports when the problem is most noticeable. Also collect data on the JVM (you can use JConsole and/or JVisualVM).

When first diagnosing bad performance I always do the "USE" method, Utilization, Saturation and Error.

So first, look for Errors in logs.

Then look for any resource becoming Saturated (CPUs, Memory etc...)

Finally Look at the Utilization of each resource, having a client server layout will make this easier, if this is not the case you will need to drill down to process level to know whether its Java or the DB.

Once you have collected this data you can direct your tunning efforts accordingly. Going this approach will only make you waste time and sometimes even mask problems or induce new ones.

You can come back later with this data and we can take a look!